# On cyclicity of fixed point algebra of flip automorphism

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $M$ be a von Neumann algebra having a cyclic vector in $\mathcal{H}$, is the fixed point subalgebra under the flip automorphism on $M\otimes M$ has a cyclic vector in $\mathcal{H}\otimes \mathcal{H}$. Furthermore, what is the commutant of the fixed point algebra under flip?

Comment: What do you think the fixed point subalgebra is in this case?  Can you then perform a calculation with the cyclic vector for $M$?

Comment: I tried with your idea before not really getting significant what we want to prove